# How to load javascript in PowerBuilder WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, powerbuilder

I'm using the new WebBrowser object in PowerBuilder 2019 R2 for the first time. I have a requirement to have it access a web page that has js scripts in it. In the call to the site, I pass several arguments, including which form I want. The scripts load the form and populate it. If they fail, it just loads a page where you can select a form and load it manually. If I run the call in Google Chrome, the correct form loads correctly. If I "activate" it in the PB WebBrowser object, it just loads the page, but no form.

Is there anything that needs to be configured or called to have javascript run in the WebBrowser object?
Is there any way I can debug it or get a log of what is going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is not the problem of loading javascript, but IE version of WebBrowser object. by default, the webbrowser control is equivalent to IE7, that causes lot of problem, maybe lead to js script error.

Browser emulation version can be set by registry of FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"myprogram.exe"=dword:00002af8
"pb105.exe"=dword:00002af8

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"myprogram.exe"=dword:00002af8
```

for details, may refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

or "A Brief Guide to FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION" at https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2016/01/a-brief-guide-to-feature_browser_emulation/

Comment: This post is about the new chromium based WebBrowser object in PowerBuilder 2019 R2, not the IE based WebBrowser in PowerBuilder 12.
Lastmboy, did you find a solution to this issue?